# Overlay a mask with transparency on a 3-dimentional image

Tags: python

I want to overlay color over a particular object for semantic segmentation. The overlay should be transparent enough so as to be able to view the object behind the overlay. The image shape is (x,y,3), i.e. no alpha channel. Due to the model, I don't want to add an extra alpha layer in the source image.
Currently, I am doing it as follows:

```
>> image.shape
(720, 1280, 3)
>> m.shape # my original mask with boolean values
(720, 1280) 
>> mask = np.stack((m,m,m), axis=2)
>> mask.shape
(720, 1280, 3)
>> image = np.where(mask, (255,0,0), image) # Red overlay (255,0,0)
```

But the object in image comes out to be completely opaque. Is there some way, to overlay color with some transparency, and in end, keeping the original 3 dimensional image unchanged?

Answer (score 1):

```
# First create the image with alpha channel
rgba = cv2.cvtColor(rgb_data, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)

# Then assign the mask to the last channel of the image
rgba[:, :, 3] = alpha_data
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate?